# Disable Intellisense on a line of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Is there any attribute I can apply to make Intellisense ignore a line of code? It keeps giving me an error on a line that compiles just fine. If not, is there another way to disable Intellisense on a particular line.

**Edit:** The line specified is this, used for making a bitmap font:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, pos, srcNullable, Color.White);
```

Comment: what line are you talking about ?

Comment: Are you using deprecated (or soon to be deprecated) functionality?

Comment: @Tigran The line is `spriteBatch.Draw(texture, pos, srcNullable, Color.White);` This is in Monogame. `texture` is a `Texture2D`, `pos` is a `Vector2`, `srcNullable` is a `Rectangle?`, and the last argument is a `Color`, as specified in the definition.

Comment: This is usually due to an ill-referenced library. Maybe you're using a .Net Framework 4.5 library in a 4.0 project? Also, make sure you're using the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color class, and not the System.Drawing.Color one.

Comment: I checked the Color. It compiles just fine, it's just Intellisense messing up.

Comment: Can you post the message it shows?

Comment: It says it has invalid arguments: `The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle?, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color)' has some invalid arguments`